# Error of duplicated definations of node in ts

Tags: node.js, typescript

The open-source program used to be good but nowadays it seems having the error with that, saying:

> 1) ../../../../node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:32:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: SlowBuffer, BufferEncoding, Buffer....
>
> 2) ../../../../node_modules/_@types_node@10.12.18@@types/node/index.d.ts:41:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: SlowBuffer, BufferEncoding, Buffer ....

From the given descriptions it seems we've got duplicated defination ts files, but how to solve that? I cannot find '_@types_node@10.12.18@@types'?

Here're some screenshots in Visual Studio Code:

1) [image]

2) [image]

For open-source logs, please see: https://travis-ci.org/eggjs/egg/jobs/481648636